# Navigating through JSON with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

OK, I have been searching through this site to find anything similar or enlightening, but I am completely stuck. I am getting some valid JSON and need to parse through it to extract prices. I'm not getting very far.

Here's the JSON:

```
{
  "result": "success",
  "prices": {
    "vdc": {
      "monthly": "1.00"
    },
    "network": {
      "private": {
        "monthly": "2.00"
      },
      "public": {
        "\/22 (1,111 IP Addresses)": {
          "monthly": "3.00"
        },
        "\/21 (2,222 IP Addresses)": {
          "monthly": "4.00"
        },
        "\/20 (3,333 IP Addresses)": {
          "monthly": "5.00"
        },
        "\/19 (5,555 IP Addresses)": {
          "monthly": "6.00"
        },
        "\/18 (6,666 IP Addresses)": {
          "monthly": "7.00"
        },
        "\/17 (7,777 IP Addresses)": {
          "monthly": "8.00"
        },
        "\/16 (8,888 IP Addresses)": {
          "monthly": "9.00"
        },
        "\/25 (111 IP Addresses)": {
          "monthly": "10.00"
        },
        "\/26 (55 IP Addresses)": {
          "monthly": "11.00"
        },
        "\/27 (22 IP Addresses)": {
          "monthly": "12.00"
        },
        "\/28 (11 IP Addresses)": {
          "monthly": "13.00"
        },
        "\/29 (5 IP Addresses)": {
          "monthly": "14.00"
        },
        "\/23 (900 IP Addresses)": {
          "monthly": "15.00"
        },
        "\/24 (333 IP Addresses)": {
          "monthly": "16.00"
        }
      }
    },
    "blocks": {
      "22": {
        "monthly": "17.00"
      },
      "21": {
        "monthly": "18.00"
      },
      "20": {
        "monthly": "19.00"
      },
      "19": {
        "monthly": "20.00"
      },
      "18": {
        "monthly": "21.00"
      },
      "17": {
        "monthly": "22.00"
      },
      "16": {
        "monthly": "23.00"
      },
      "25": {
        "monthly": "24.00"
      },
      "26": {
        "monthly": "25.00"
      },
      "27": {
        "monthly": "28.00"
      },
      "28": {
        "monthly": "29.00"
      },
      "29": {
        "monthly": "30.00"
      },
      "23": {
        "monthly": "24.00"
      },
      "24": {
        "monthly": "25.00"
      }
    },
    "server": {
      "cpu": {
        "monthly": "26.00"
      },
      "ram": {
        "monthly": "27.00"
      }
    },
    "volume": {
      "gb": {
        "monthly": "28.00"
      }
    },
    "snapshot": {
      "gb": {
        "monthly": "29.00"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Tested and validated at jsonlint [dot] com.

After much trying, testing, trying, banging head against my keyboard, trying...this is what I currently have, but it's not producing the desired results (I'll tell you what those are, right after the code snippet).

```
function gp(x){ 
    for(var i in x){ 
        console.log('700: ',  x[i] );

        if(x[i] != 'success'){
            console.log(733);
            console.log(x[i]);

            for(var j in x[i]){
                console.log(736);
                console.log(x[i][j]);
            }
        }
     }
}
```

In the console, I see something like this:

[image]

What I really would like to see (or find or parse to) is, for example, the monthly price for "gb" from the "volume" element (or is it an item?).

Ideally, I would like to find "volume", "ram" and "cpu" – verify that it's the volume, ram and cpu – then get the monthly price. I did try a few things with JSON parsing, but obviously, I haven't mastered that quite yet either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you're talking about *navigating* an object, not *parsing*.  The word "parse" is about interpreting a string to recognize a syntax. It looks like you've already had your JSON string parsed into an object.

Comment: So I should look for help with navigating an object then, right. OK. I really appreciate your feedback. Thanks.

Comment: how did you get your json in the first place. is it by using ajax or post or what exactly. knowing that might help to post a suitable answer for you

Comment: `volume` can be found using `x.volume`, `ram` can be found using `x.server.ram`, and `cpu` can be found using `x.server.cpu`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: What is the o/p format you are looking at?

Comment: @mamdouh alramadan AJAX POST

Comment: great, then you have the callback function, aren't you?

Comment: @ASAD: TypeError: x.server is undefined

Comment: Is `x` the object you have posted the JSON representation of?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to find the objects "volume", "ram" and "cpu" that's simple:

```
var volume = x.prices.volume;
var ram = x.prices.server.ram;
var cpu = x.prices.server.cpu;
```

or you can simply use them directly:

```
console.log(x.prices.volume);
```

If you want to find the monthly prices then:

```
var prices = x.prices;
console.log('volume, monthly=', prices.volume.gb.monthly);
console.log('cpu, monthly=', prices.server.cpu.monthly);
console.log('ram, monthly=', prices.server.ram.monthly);
```

---

Javascript objects are really simple, there are only 2 syntax for accessing them:

```
// If the key you're accessing is a constant (hardcoded):
object.key = value;

// If the key you're accessing is stored in another variable:
var k = "key";
object[k] = value;

// Alternatively:
object["key"] = value;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm just a bit confused, but heres an example.  Save your json to an variable and just go down the tree with node names (unless don't have any).

***This should get the volume monthly***

```
 json.prices.volume.gb.monthly
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PKUBA/

Comment: Freaking magic! Thank you for your help. I'm really impressed.