# How to add specific values to highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have the following string as a result of an ajax call:

> "A, B, C, D, A, B, C, D, A, B, C, D"

What I want is to put all my `A` characters in a column from a chart, then all the `B` and `C` in the same way, the problem is that in my ajax call I do something like this:

```
var t = data.d;
var split;
var datos = t.split(",");
```

And then I make a `for loop` to select only `A` only `B`, etc.

My question is, what can I do to put my for value `(datos[i] for example)`, in my chart, I know that must be an array to be added but I don't know exactly what can I do.

This is an [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mAYjqL) of what I want

Comment: so.. you have a working example of what you want to do... but you're asking how to do it? copy the code from your link.. what is the problem?

Comment: @Pamblam the code from my example is to see how I want the chart, because I add the values manually, in other words my question is how can I add that `var datos` to highchart series[]

Comment: Your question is about how to use basic data structures in Javascript. It's a simple object with a simple array. Voting to close. If you have to ask about something this basic then you're going to be asking questions any time you need to do *anything* and SO is not a free code writing service. [Here](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/data-structures-with-javascript-stack-and-queue--cms-23348) is a tutorial on JS data structures. Teach a man to fish..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Navigating through JSON with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150642/navigating-through-json-with-javascript)

Comment: @Pamblam maybe my question was not clear at all, I don't have problems with JS, my problem was attempting to add my values to a highchart, but thanks for your time, I'm going to try to solve this and of course, if I have a problem I'll come here, have a nice day.

Comment: do you mean do you want to put that array of letters in X-Axis?

Comment: I think I understand what you're looking for, but I want to make sure before I post an answer... lets say you have this array `var data = ["A","B","A","B","A","B","C","A"];` are you trying to get a count of "A" and use that value in the chart?

Comment: I don't know this is something you are looking for? http://jsbin.com/rimatot/edit?console,output

Answer (score 0):

You need to create variable and setup your settings as JSON then pass it to `highcharts(options)`

for example

```
var options = {some:value,some:[..array..]}
```

then customize `series` option and loop over your array(); and push name,data like this

```
options["series"] = [];
var names = array();//"A, B, C".split(",");
var data = [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]];

for(var i=0;i<array().length;i++){

options["series"].push({
name:"Letter " + array()[i], // Letter A
data:data[i] // [1,1]
});

}
```

Your Example should be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  chart();
});

function chart() {

   // create variable options to store your settings

    var options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Letters'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ':P'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Col 1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3', 'Col 4'],
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: ':P',
                align: 'high'
            },
            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' letters'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -40,
            y: 80,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
            shadow: true
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }

    // the lets customize series data

    options["series"] = [];
    var my_letters = letters();// see letters function below
    var my_values = values();// see values function below

    for(var i=0;i<my_letters.length;i++){
        options["series"].push({
            name: 'Letter '+my_letters[i],
            data: my_values[i]
        });
    }

  $('#container').highcharts(options);
}

function letters() {
  var data = "A, B, A, B, A, B, C, A";
  var split = data.split(",");
  return split;
}
function values() {
  var data = [[1,1], [2,2], [3,3], [4,4], [5,5], [6,6], [7,7], [8,8]];
  return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your js code in your sample.

I put the array in the x-axis

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var splitx = array();
  chart(splitx);
});
function chart(splitx) {
  $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Letters'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ':P'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: splitx            
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: ':P',
                align: 'high'
            },
            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' letters'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -40,
            y: 80,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
            shadow: true
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Letter A',
            data: [4, 4]
        }, {
            name: 'Letter B',
            data: [3, 3]
        }, {
            name: 'Letter C',
            data: [1, 1]
        }]
    });
}

function array() {
  var data = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H";
  return data.split(",");  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of how you can parse your input string to your chart in order to get letter counts as values:

https://jsfiddle.net/g92acxt7/

```
var input = "A, B, A, B, A, B, C, A";
var letters = input.split(', ');
var count = {};

// Counting letters
letters.forEach(function(letter) {
    count[letter] = ++count[letter] || 1;
});
console.log(count); // {A: 4, B: 3, C: 1}

var options = {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Letters'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: ':P'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Col 1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3', 'Col 4'],
    title: {
      text: null
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: ':P',
      align: 'high'
    },
    labels: {
      overflow: 'justify'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    valueSuffix: ' letters'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      }
    }
  },
  legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    x: -40,
    y: 80,
    floating: true,
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
    shadow: true
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Letter A',
    // Insert letters counts
    data: [count['A'], count['A']]
  }, {
    name: 'Letter B',
    // Insert letters counts
    data: [count['B'], count['B']]
  }, {
    name: 'Letter C',
    // Insert letters counts
    data: [count['C'], count['C']]
  }]
};
```

Highcharts.chart(document.getElementById('container'), options);